# Enterprise NoSQL Stack Solution for Mobile/Web

Tags: mongodb, mobile, couchdb, nosql

I'm tasked with investigating for our firm a full-stack solution where we'll be using a NoSQL database backend.  It'll most likely be fed from a data warehouse and/or operational data store of some type in near-realtime (hopefully :).  It will be used mainly by our mobile and web applications via REST.

**A few requirements/assumptions**:

- It will be read-only (in the near term) and consumed by clients in REST format
- It has to be scalable
- Fast response time
- Enterprise support - or if lacking actual support, something industry proven if open-source (basically management wants to hold
  someone accountable if something in the stack fails)
- Minimal client data transformations - i.e: data should be stored in as close to ready-to-use format as possible
- Service API Management of some sort will most likely be needed (eg: 3scale)
- Services will be used internally, but solution shouldn't prevent us from exposing them externally as a longterm goal
- Micro-services are preferable (provided sufficient API management is in place)
- We have in-house expertise in Java and Grails for our mobile/portal solutions

**Some of the options I was tossing around were:**

- CouchDB: inherently returns REST - no need for translation layer - as
  long as clients speak REST, we're all good
- MongoDB: need a REST layer in between client and DB - haven't found a widely used one based on my investigation (the ones on Mongo's site all seem in their infancy - i.e: RestHeart)

**Some questions I have:**

- Do I need an appserver?  Or any layer in between the client and DB
  for performance/caching reasons?  I was thinking a reverse-proxy like
  nginx would be a good idea for this?
- Why not use CouchDB in this solution if it supports REST out of the box?

I'm struggling with deciding between which NoSQL DB to use, whether or not I need a REST translation layer, appserver, etc.  I've read the pros and cons of each and mostly they say go Mongo - but for what I'm trying to do the lack of a mature REST layer is concerning.

I'm just looking for some ideas, tips, lessons learned that anyone out there would be willing to share.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to the party! **A few requirements**: questions on StackOverflow need to be about specific programming problems. They should not endorse opinion based discussions. The [tour should be taken](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour) and should be understood. Repeat if necessary. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with exposing the database directly to the client is that most databases do not support permission control which is as fine-grained as you want it to be. You often can not allow a client to view and edit its own data while also forbidding it from viewing and editing any data of other users or even worse from the server itself. At least not when you still want a sane database schema.

You will also often find yourself in the situation that you have a document with several fields of which only some are supposed to be under the control of the user and others are not. I can, for example, edit the content of this answer, but I can not edit the time it was posted, the name it was posted under or its voting score. So far I have never seen a database system which can handle permission for individual fields (when anyone has: feel free to post in the comments).

You might think about trying to handle this on the client and just don't offer any user interface for editing said fields. But that will only work in a trusted environment. When you have untrusted users, they could create a clone of your client-sided application which does expose this functionality. There is no way for you to tell the difference between the genuine client and a clone, especially not when you don't have a smart application server (and even then it is practically impossible).

For that reason it is almost always required to have an application server between clients and database which handles authentication and permission management of the clients and only forwards those requests to the persistence layer which are permitted.

Answer (score 0):

I totally agree with the answer from @Philipp. In the case of using CouchDB you will minimum want to use a proxy server in front to enable SSL.

Almost all of your requirements can be fulfilled by CouchDB. Especially the upcoming v2 will give you the "datacenter-needs".

But it's simply very complex to answer what should be the right tool for you purpose. If you get some business model requirements on top like lets say: throttling - then you will definitely need an application server middleware like http://mcavage.me/node-restify/

Maybe it's a good idea to spend some money to professionals like
http://www.neighbourhood.ie/couchdb-support/ ? (I'm not involved)